# Separating row data out into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a customers table that houses contacts. Each contact is added as another row to that customer.

I want to create my query so that I can create columns for `contact1`, `contact2`, `contact3` and so forth. What's the best way to do this?

My rows are dynamic and I have been looking into unpivot and pivot but I'm not sure how I would build that into my query as I have a few joins and other data in the query.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aee9/1/0)

Comment: You are trying to do something wrong, creating a column for each row ?!

Comment: How many contacts are possible?  Is there a set number?

Comment: Google "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: if you want a single column with a list of values -- that is actually easier then making columns... unless you know exactly how many columns.

Comment: why is your fiddle in mySQL when this question is tagged sqlserver?

Comment: @Bes - Rows are duplicated since each contact is associated with the parent account. but I want to delete the repeat rows and move the contact data into seperate columns (contact1, contactphone1, contact2, contactphone2)

Comment: @Charlie - No there is no set number of contacts per account

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic pivot query is what you need. See this:
[http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

and this:
[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)